# Unable to build bitcoin in a VirtualBox running Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox, bitcoin

I have been following instructions given at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/gitian-building.md

When I run `./bin/gbuild -c bitcoin=HEAD ../bitcoin/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-linux.yml`, I get the following error-

```
./bin/gbuild:21:in `system!': failed to run on-target setarch x86_64 bash -x < var/build-script > var/build.log 2>&1 (RuntimeError)
        from ./bin/gbuild:137:in `build_one_configuration'
        from ./bin/gbuild:270:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from ./bin/gbuild:265:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:265:in `block in <main>'
        from ./bin/gbuild:263:in `each'
        from ./bin/gbuild:263:in `<main>'
```

The following is the content var/build.log file-

```
+ set -e
+ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
+ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
+ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
+ LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
+ umask 002
+ export OUTDIR=/home/ubuntu/out
+ OUTDIR=/home/ubuntu/out
+ GBUILD_BITS=64
+ GBUILD_CACHE_ENABLED=1
+ GBUILD_PACKAGE_CACHE=/home/ubuntu/cache/bitcoin-linux-0.12
+ GBUILD_COMMON_CACHE=/home/ubuntu/cache/common
+ MAKEOPTS=(-j2)
+ REFERENCE_DATETIME='2015-06-01 00:00:00'
+ REFERENCE_DATE=2015-06-01
+ REFERENCE_TIME=00:00:00
+ cd build/bitcoin
+ git reset -q --hard
+ git clean -q -f -d
+ cd build
+ WRAP_DIR=/home/ubuntu/wrapped
+ HOSTS='i686-pc-linux-gnu x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
+ CONFIGFLAGS='--enable-glibc-back-compat --enable-reduce-exports LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++'
+ FAKETIME_HOST_PROGS=
+ FAKETIME_PROGS='date ar ranlib nm strip'
+ export QT_RCC_TEST=1
+ QT_RCC_TEST=1
+ export GZIP=-9n
+ GZIP=-9n
+ export 'TAR_OPTIONS=--mtime=2015-06-01\ 00:00:00'
+ TAR_OPTIONS='--mtime=2015-06-01\ 00:00:00'
+ export TZ=UTC
+ TZ=UTC
++ pwd
+ export BUILD_DIR=/home/ubuntu/build
+ BUILD_DIR=/home/ubuntu/build
+ mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/wrapped
+ test -n 1
+ export SOURCES_PATH=/home/ubuntu/cache/common
+ SOURCES_PATH=/home/ubuntu/cache/common
+ export BASE_CACHE=/home/ubuntu/cache/bitcoin-linux-0.12
+ BASE_CACHE=/home/ubuntu/cache/bitcoin-linux-0.12
+ mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/cache/bitcoin-linux-0.12 /home/ubuntu/cache/common
+ for prog in '${FAKETIME_PROGS}'
+ echo '#!/bin/bash'
+ echo 'REAL=`which -a date | grep -v /home/ubuntu/wrapped/date | head -1`'
+ echo 'export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1'
+ echo 'export FAKETIME="2015-06-01 00:00:00"'
+ echo '$REAL $@'
+ chmod +x /home/ubuntu/wrapped/date
+ for prog in '${FAKETIME_PROGS}'
+ echo '#!/bin/bash'
+ echo 'REAL=`which -a ar | grep -v /home/ubuntu/wrapped/ar | head -1`'
+ echo 'export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1'
+ echo 'export FAKETIME="2015-06-01 00:00:00"'
+ echo '$REAL $@'
+ chmod +x /home/ubuntu/wrapped/strip
+ for i in '$HOSTS'
+ for i in '$HOSTS'
+ export PATH=/home/ubuntu/wrapped:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ PATH=/home/ubuntu/wrapped:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ cd bitcoin
++ pwd
+ BASEPREFIX=/home/ubuntu/build/bitcoin/depends
+ for i in '$HOSTS'
+ make -j2 -C /home/ubuntu/build/bitcoin/depends HOST=i686-pc-linux-gnu
make: *** /home/ubuntu/build/bitcoin/depends: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```